# Conservation law for quantum field theory with boundary

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, noethers-theorem, boundary-terms

Consider a scalar field theory defined on 1+1 D space time where the space is limited to [-L,L].

The Lagrangian density of the theory is

\begin{equation}
\dot\Phi^2-(\partial_x\Phi)^2-h\partial_x\Phi(x=-L)-\tilde h\partial_x\Phi(x=L)
\end{equation}
where the two last terms are the terms acting only at the edges.

How does equation of motion and Noether's theorem look like in this case?

The variation of action gives
\begin{equation}
\delta S=0=\int_{-L}^L \mathrm{d}x\int dt \left(\frac{\delta\mathcal{L}}{\delta\Phi}\delta\phi+\frac{\delta \mathcal L}{\delta \dot\Phi}\delta\dot\Phi+\frac{\delta \mathcal{L}}{\delta \partial_x\Phi}\delta\partial_x\Phi \right)
\end{equation}
Integrating by parts, we obtain
\begin{equation}
\delta S=\iint dx dt\left[\left(\frac{\delta\mathcal{L}}{\delta\Phi}-\partial_t \frac{\delta \mathcal{L}}{\delta\partial_t\Phi}-\partial_x \frac{\delta \mathcal{L}}{\delta\partial_x\Phi} \right)\delta\Phi+\partial_t\left(\frac{\delta\mathcal{L}}{\delta\partial_t\Phi}\delta\Phi \right)+\partial_x\left(\frac{\delta\mathcal{L}}{\delta\partial_x\Phi}\delta\Phi \right) \right]
\end{equation}

But, now we can't possibly neglect the boundary terms.

Defining $\vec\nabla=(\partial_t,\partial_x)^T$, we can write the last two terms as
\begin{align}
\int dxdt\vec\nabla\cdot(\vec\nabla\Phi\delta\Phi)=\int dt (\partial_x\Phi)\delta\Phi\big\vert_{x=-L}^{x=L}
\end{align}

Thus, we have to kind of consistent boundary conditions:

$\begin{aligned}
\left.\partial_x \Phi\right|_{x=-L,L} &=0 \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad \text{Neumann condition,}\\
\left.\delta \Phi\right|_{x=-L, L} &=0=\left.\partial_t\Phi\right|_{x=-L,L} \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\text{Dirichlet condition.}
\end{aligned}$

With the usual Euler-Lagrange equation
\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta \mathcal L}{\delta \Phi}=\partial_\mu \frac{\delta \mathcal L}{\delta\partial_\mu\Phi}
\end{equation}

Using
\begin{equation}
{T^\mu}_\nu=\frac{\delta \mathcal L}{\delta\partial_\mu\Phi}\partial_\nu\Phi-{\delta^\mu}_\nu \mathcal L
\end{equation}

I want to see if the energy-current $\frac{d}{dt}\int_{-L}^L dx{T^0}_0$ is still $0$, but I am confused by the two boundary terms in the Lagrangian.